# React Simple WebRTC Choose Devices

Tags: reactjs, typescript, simplewebrtc

I'm working on a video conference app in react + typescript using Simple WebRTC and I want to implement a view to let the user choose their audio input, output and also video device.

I noticed that the library handles their own store that has devices and media fields. Also the library have a component to display the available devices for audio and video but I don't see any action to change the media in the store because that's what the `SWRTC.Video` component (what I use to show the video screen) receives to show the video and also the audio.

What I have is the `deviceId` on the `<select>` change but I need the media from the deviceId to pass it as a prop to the `SWRTC.Video` component. I've been reading the docs at https://docs.simplewebrtc.com/ but I don't see any action that support that also they have few examples so If anyone have worked on something similar before maybe could help me.

Answer (score 0):

user `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to get all devices. Every device has a field `deviceId`. When you request you stream with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(opts)` you can add the option `deviceId` to the options to get your selected device.

example opts :

```
const opts = {
  audio: {
    deviceId: 'someID'
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, what I got is an object of MediaStream like this
`{ active: true, id: "I71BK8NPReSNL45o4AuwRlJc43IDC1tmG4M4", onactive: null, onaddtrack: null, oninactive: null, onremovetrack: null }`
But that's not the type the SWRTC.Video component media prop receives.

Comment: The type of the library component it's this: `interface Media { ...; hark?: Hark; height?: number; id: string; inputDetected?: false | true; inputLost?: number; kind: audio | video; lastSpokeAt?: Date; loaded?: false | true; localDisabled: boolean; owner?: string; profile?: low | medium | high; remoteDisabled: boolean; renderMirrored: boolean; replaces?: string; roomAddress?: string; screenCapture: boolean; shared?: false | true; source: local | remote; speaking: boolean; stream: MediaStream; track: MediaStreamTrack; utilityStream?: MediaStream; volume: number; width?: number; }`